# mysql inner join count issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2.

Table1:

```
log_id | postcode
1      |  LS11LS
```

Table2:

```
region | postcode
Leeds     | LS1
Leeds     | LS11
```

When I use the following query,

```
SELECT table2.region 'Region', 
       Count(table1.postcode) AS 'count' 
FROM   table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
   ON table1.postcode LIKE Concat(table2.postcode, '%')
```

I get

```
Region   |   count
Leeds    |    2
```

where it should be 1 because there is only one record on Table1. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the final solution for this thing after 8 hours . by the end user post code entry , trim the post code off any spaces , and then str_replace the spaces to nothing , and then take off the last 3 letter / numbers of the string . and save it as an additional column along with the original postcode , now you will have post codes store like LS1 . LS11 , and instead of inner join using like , use = . this is i believe the only way out there.

see [This link](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10363132-UK-Postcode-mysql-partial-match-array-please-help/page2&s=281744767b032f2943a94469f74efe3c) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT table2.region 'Region', 
    COUNT( DISTINCT table1.log_id )  as 'count' 
FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON 
        table1.postcode LIKE CONCAT( table2.postcode,  '%' )
```

I replaced postcode with log_id as it perhaps is your unique column.

*EDIT: While I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, here's an alternative approach using a subquery:*

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(1) as 'Count'
FROM Table1 T
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT T2.Region, T.PostCode
        FROM table1 T
            INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON 
                    T.postcode LIKE CONCAT( T2.postcode,  '%' )
    ) T2 ON T.PostCode = T2.PostCode
```

Comment: other entries by the end user could be the same on table 1 so i dont want to distinct it , i just want it to count this one once

Comment: @AhmedElGamil -- it's counting it twice because it finds 2 matches in table2 -- 1 for LS1 and 1 for LS11 -- hence the reason you'd need to count distinct.  Sorry this didn't help.  You could just count DISTINCT log_id perhaps...

Comment: thank you for your answer , i will look for something that maybe distinct the join values from the region table and then do the count.

Comment: @AhmedElGamil -- I made another attempt -- see edits.  Hope it at least gets you going in the right direction.  Best of luck!

Comment: still counting it twice ..as a workaround  i made a trigger on the table to dump the count for each row once inserted and forced in case it was 2 to be 1 .. mercy from code quality audit .... but again thanks for trying with me

Comment: @AhmedElGamil -- not really sure -- this counts 1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d39/5

Comment: hmm , it is working now , an hour ago it didn't .. this is working . thank you very much sir you saved me couple of hours to sleep now.

Comment: @AhmedElGamil -- pretty much out of ideas.  Not sure why this wouldn't work though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80b95/12

Comment: because [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60b0c/1) ... ok the final solution for this thing after 8 hours . by the end user post code entry , trim the post code off any spaces , and then str_replace the spaces to nothing , and then take off the last 3 letter / numbers of the string . and save it as an additional column along with the original postcode , now you will have post codes store like LS1 . LS11 , and instead of inner join using like , use = . this is i believe the only way out there.